# Refreshing a RecyclerView when all items are removed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that shows a list of items.

If there is no item to show, The recyclerview shows one item with a specific view (to tell the user there is no item instead of a white screen).

Within **HistoryFragment**:

```
private void initRecyclerView(Boolean isNoResult){
        HistoryRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new HistoryRecyclerViewAdapter(mContext, mRecords, **isNoResult**);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Within HistoryRecyclerViewAdapter:

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

        if(**isEmpty**) {
            **view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem_prhistory_empty, parent, false);**
        } else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem_prhistory, parent, false);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
}
```

So, it's possible to remove items one by one, if we click on them.

I would like to set `isEmpty` to `true` and refresh the `RecyclerView` when the dataSet is null.

I already know where to call that **method** but I really don't know how I can do that? (i.e. refresh the `RecyclerView` with `isEmpty = true` so I can display the cell that explain to the user that there is no record anymore).

Comment: Please post the full code of your **Adapter** class including all `override` methods and all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't inflate different view-holders, because when the adapter has no items, not a single one of them will ever be inflated. Instead one can wrap the `RecyclerView` together with a "no data" `Fragment` into a `ViewFlipper`, which then can be switched to the `Fragment`, when the `RecyclerView` adapter has no items.

Comment: He wanted to show another item view when data list is empty rather than showing a new page/fragment of "No Data". (It might be his specific requirements for development)

Comment: I'm able to read by myself, there is no need to repeat... this is simply a crappy approach, therefore I've provided a rather plausible approach. There is absolutely no advance in adding a fake item, only in order to add/remove it, only to display a message.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use an empty view outside of RecyclerView but in case you like to do what you want:

1.in onCreateViewHolder only inflate one layout which has empty and item views

2. on item delete check if your array is empty and then add a null item
   then in onBindViewHolder check the model if model is Null visible empty view otherwise show item view

summary:

onBind:

model is null : empty View visible

model is not null: item View visible

Answer (score 0):

use interface to refresh the `RecyclerView` after remove something like this

```
public interface RefreshRecyclerView {

    public void Refresh();
}
```

then in activity or fragment implement the interface

```
Fragment implements RefreshRecyclerView
```

you will have override method like this

```
 @Override
    public void Refresh() {
       // set adapter again here 
    }
```

then pass the interface to adapter like this

```
RefreshRecyclerView refresh = (RefreshRecyclerView) this;

yourRecycler.setadapter(refresh);
```

fially when user clicked on adapter use this

```
refresh. Refresh();
```